Display only the first value of the dropdown menu. on Altair Chart
I would like my chart to show only the first value of the dropdown menu (the red dots representing "USA" in my case), instead of displaying all of the countries prior to any filtering. I used the code in the answer to this question, but all of the countries show up and the dropdown menu isn't responsive.
from vega_datasets import data
cars_data = data.cars()

cars_unique_vals = list(cars_data['Origin'].unique())

dropdown = alt.binding_select(
    options=cars_unique_vals,
    name='Select Origin: '
)

xcol_param = alt.param(
    value=cars_unique_vals[0],
    bind=dropdown
)


alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon',
    color='Origin',
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).transform_calculate(
    x=f'datum[{xcol_param.name}]'
).add_params(
    xcol_param
)


This is a typo. alt.Chart(source).mark... The correct one is this. alt.Chart(cars_data).mark...

Thanks, but swapping this out still didn't work.

If you modify what I pointed out in my comment in your code, you will see the USA in the drop down correctly. I checked with altair:5.3.0 in my environment.

My altair is also 5.3.0 but the dropdown menu still isn't responsive. Additionally, I want only the points associated with "USA" to be displayed by default, then display the other points for "Japan" and "Europe" when these values are selected in the menu. from vega_datasets import data

`cars_unique_vals = list(cars_data['Origin'].unique())
dropdown = alt.binding_select(
options=cars_unique_vals,
name='Select Origin: '
)
xcol_param = alt.param(
value=cars_unique_vals[0],
bind=dropdown
)
alt.Chart(cars_data).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
x='Horsepower',
y='Miles_per_Gallon',
color='Origin',
tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).transform_calculate(
x=f'datum[{xcol_param.name}]'
).add_params(
xcol_param
)`

Try this: `dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=cars_unique_vals,name='Select Origin: ')
xcol_param = alt.selection_point(fields=['Origin'], value=cars_unique_vals[0], bind=dropdown)
alt.Chart(cars_data).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
x='Horsepower',
y='Miles_per_Gallon',
color='Origin',
tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
).add_params(
xcol_param
).transform_filter(
xcol_param
)`
